# Find Date Recycle Bin Was Last Emptied

Tags: windows, date, bin, recycle

Where on my computer would I be able to find the last date that the recycle bin was last emptied, would such an event be stored in the windows system logs? and if so where?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it would be recorded anywhere in the event logs, but there might be file system traces left.

UPDATE: using UnixTools I can confirm there are file system traces left. If you navigate to `C:\$Recycle.Bin` there will be a number of entries (even with the bin appearing empty). These entries appear to correspond to security IDs ([SIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)) on the system. In my test the most recently modified one was the date and time I last emptied the recycle bin.

This means it probably can be retrieved programatically with the Windows API.

Comment: er, probably only as long as you haven't added anything to the bin since it was emptied. You're talking about the last modified date right?

Comment: Correct. If the recycle bin is completely empty then you can get the date/time it was emptied. Else you get the date/time the latest file was 'recycled'.